# Remove rows from two DFs that have uncommon column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have these two DFs

Active:

```
Customer_ID | product_No| Rating
7           | 111       | 3.0
7           | 222       | 1.0
7           | 333       | 5.0
7           | 444       | 3.0
```

User:

```
Customer_ID | product_No| Rating
9           | 111       | 2.0
9           | 222       | 5.0
9           | 666       | 5.0
9           | 555       | 3.0
```

I want to find the ratings of the common products that both users rated (e.g. 111,222) and remove any uncommon products (e.g. 444,333,555,666). So the new DFs should be like this:

Active:

```
Customer_ID | product_No| Rating
7           | 111       | 3.0
7           | 222       | 1.0
```

User:

```
Customer_ID | product_No| Rating
9           | 111       | 2.0
9           | 222       | 5.0
```

I do not know how to do this without for loops. Can you help me, please

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
ratings = pd.read_csv("ratings.csv",names['Customer_ID','product_No','Rating'])
active=ratings[ratings['UserID']==7]
user=ratings[ratings['UserID']==9]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can firstly get the common `product_No` using *set intersection* and then use `isin` method to filter on the original data frames:

```
common_product = set(active.product_No).intersection(user.product_No)

common_product
# {111, 222}

active[active.product_No.isin(common_product)]

#Customer_ID   product_No   Rating
#0         7          111      3.0
#1         7          222      1.0

user[user.product_No.isin(common_product)]

#Customer_ID   product_No   Rating
#0         9          111      2.0
#1         9          222      5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `query` referencing the other dataframes

```
Active.query('product_No in @User.product_No')

   Customer_ID  product_No  Rating
0            7         111     3.0
1            7         222     1.0

User.query('product_No in @Active.product_No')

   Customer_ID  product_No  Rating
0            9         111     2.0
1            9         222     5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using `INNER JOIN` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('b.csv')
print df1
print df2

df_ij = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='product_No', how='inner')
print df_ij

df_list = []
for df_e,suffx in zip([df1,df2],['_x','_y']):
    df_e = df_ij[['Customer_ID'+suffx,'product_No','Rating'+suffx]]
    df_e.columns = list(df1)
    df_list.append(df_e)

print df_list[0]
print df_list[1]
```

It gives the following output:

```
# print df1
   Customer_ID  product_No  Rating
0            7         111       3
1            7         222       1
2            7         333       5
3            7         444       3

# print df2
   Customer_ID  product_No  Rating
0            9         111       2
1            9         222       5
2            9         777       5
3            9         555       3

# print the INNER JOINed df
   Customer_ID_x  product_No  Rating_x  Customer_ID_y  Rating_y
0              7         111         3              9         2
1              7         222         1              9         5

# print the first df you want, with common 'product_No'
   Customer_ID  product_No  Rating
0            7         111       3
1            7         222       1

# print the second df you want, with common 'product_No'
   Customer_ID  product_No  Rating
0            9         111       2
1            9         222       5
```

The `inner join` selects the common rows in each `df`. Since there are common column names, for columns not used in the join, the joined `df` has added suffixes to distinguish between those column names. You then need to simply extract columns to get your required final result, by just specifying the appropriate suffix.

There is a nice example of `INNER JOIN` [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).

Answer (score 0):

Your Answer for this question is....

```
import pandas as pd
dict1={"Customer_id":[7,7,7,7],
      "Product_No":[111,222,333,444],
      "rating":[3.0,1.0,5.0,3.0]}
active=pd.DataFrame(dict1)
dict2={"Customer_id":[9,9,9,9],
      "Product_No":[111,222,666,555],
      "rating":[2.0,5.0,5.0,3.0]}
user=pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df3=pd.merge(active,user,on="Product_No",how="inner")
df3
active=df3[["Customer_id_x","Product_No","rating_x"]]
print(active)
user=df3[["Customer_id_y","Product_No","rating_y"]]
print(user)
```